# how to disable a call to onCreate when someone is pressing on my app from the task mgr

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, android-broadcast, taskmanager

I'm launching an activity from a broadcast receiver using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

My activity launches a CountDownTimer in its onCreate method.
Pressing a key kills my app (I'm calling finish()) but my app appears in the task mgr.

If I'll open the task mgr and click on my app, the onCreate method is being called again and another instance of my timer is being called.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something like the code below in your app to start your countdown timer.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

You could wrap an if statement around that to see if the countdown has started or not, if it has then set a boolean to true and if not set it to false (since the timer has stopped).

```
    if(countDownStarted == false)
    {
        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) 
        {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                countDownStarted = true;
            }

            public void onFinish() 
            {
                mTextField.setText("done!");
                countDownStarted = false;
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest-file put `launchMode` in the `<activity>` tag.

If you choose `singleTask` or `singleInstance` you won't have multiple instances of your app.

example:

```
<activity android:name=".MyFirstActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Try using that, it might solve your problem.
More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: The OP also needs to drop calling `finish()`, I think.

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. still every click on the task mgr calls the onCreate function of my activity.

Comment: drop finish ? how will I close my activity ?

Comment: @user1536033 Why close it?  And everything you've described is normal Android behaviour. You should read about the Activity life cycle.

Comment: I'm closing it because the user don't need it anymore. He answers a question and that's it. What do you suggest to do instead ?

Comment: Let the user leave it like any other app.  I don't close a web page when I'm finished with it, I just go to another one. If you code onCreate(), onPause() and onResume() properly, then your app can behave the "Android way".

Comment: but you're missing a very important thing here. my activity launches a CountDownTimer, I want it to get launched only once. I don't wan't the timer to start the countdown on every click. how I can achieve it?

Comment: @user1536033 : if you want the countdown to span multiple activity instances, you should use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead. `CountDownTimer` is the wrong tool here, as it's intended to be used within a single Activity instance. I second Simon's advice to learn about the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), by the way.

Comment: the only thing that I want is to start an activity from a broadcastreceiver, this activity will count to X seconds, on completion, I want the activity to finish. I would love to learn a better way to implement this.